# Spring 5 static resource mapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I'm migrating to spring 5. I'm moving all my xml to java config, but I'm stuck on the static resources.

In my old xml config I have resources defined as such:
`<mvc:resources mapping="/3rdparty/**" location="/3rdparty/" />`

Im adding them to my Java Config class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mypackages.*")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/3rdparty/**").addResourceLocations("/3rdparty/");


    }

     @Bean
       public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
          InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

          bean.setPrefix("/");
          bean.setSuffix(".jsp");

          return bean;
       }



}
```

Now I'm getting these errors for my resources
`No mapping for GET /myapp/gui/3rdparty/bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js`

It all worked well with the xml config.. Any ideas how I should define the pattern..

The folder structure is like this

```
ROOT
 |_WEB-INF
 |_META-INF
 |_gui
   |_3rdparty
```

I've also moved my startup to java config

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

     @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {

             AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context  = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
             context.setConfigLocation("com.mypackages.config");

             container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));


            ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container
              .addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));

            dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
            dispatcher.addMapping("/");
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Are you using Maven to build and package your application? Where is the java code located in your project - the folder structure seems be incomplete...

Comment: The code is in WEB-INF/classes..

Comment: I only specified what I thought would be relevant to the question.  the static resources are in folders under webapps/gui. When the app is deployed it follows the structure stated above

Answer (score 0):

Two things I suggest to change:

1. Use `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext#scan("com.mypackages.config")` instead of `#setConfigLocation(...)` in order to scan classes annotated with `@Configuration`. Or register a specific class directly: `#register(WebConfig.class)`.
2. Double check the argument in `#addResourceLocations("/3rdparty/")`. Your folder structure indicates that `#addResourceLocations("/gui/3rdparty/")` might work.

In Maven projects packaged as `.war`, all web resources are typically in a separated `webapp` folder, see [Maven War Plugin for reference](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html). In your case:

```
|-- pom.xml
|-- src
    |-- main
        |-- java
        |   |-- com
        |       |-- mypackages
        |           |-- config
        |               |-- WebConfig.java
        |               |-- AppInitializer.java
        |-- resources
        |-- webapp
            |-- gui
                |-- 3rdparty
                    |-- bootstrap.min.js
```

With `WebConfig.java`

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.stackoverflow.*")
@Configuration 
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

     @Override 
     public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/gui/3rdparty/**").addResourceLocations("/gui/3rdparty/");
     }
}
```

And `AppInitializer.java`:

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override 
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(WebConfig.class);

        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));

        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
}
```

}

The bootstrap resource will be available at `http://<host>:<port>/gui/3rdparty/bootstrap.min.js`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I will try prepending the /gui to the ResourceHandler. Im in the middle of upgrading to spring boot at the moment and will give this a try when that is working